# Having trouble extracting data from PDO array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

It might be the late hour or user error but I'm having trouble extracting variables from a PDO, where it would normally work. When I print_r my results by doing $array->results(), I get the following line:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [messageid] => 1 [fromid] => 2 [toid] => 1 [message] => Hello! ) )
```

However, on other projects when working with other people I have then just referred to the variable like this:

```
$result['message']
```

This is obviously after the line

```
$result = $array->results();
```

I've been troubleshooting and come to no conclusions, but I'm terrible at managing arrays so it could be something super simple. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: What about $result[0]['message']; or $result[0]->message;

Comment: I tried that, only to be greeted with the following error: "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array".

Comment: I didn't see the second approach, but I tried that and it works as intended. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @user3642576 kindly accept this answer (click the checkmark on the left side of the answer) if this has indeed helped you.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the result seems objects within array, so get your array and access object(s) inside it, to get `message` object from your `$result`, just do:

```
echo $result[0]->message;
```